# Android bottomviewnavigation adding png icon to new item

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

Opened a new project with a Bottom Navigation activity template in Android Studio.

When i try to change icon of one of the menu items with a 32x32 png file, it works on all emulator and real devices with api level > 21 but crashes on JellyBean

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:icon="@drawable/phone" //32x32 png file cause a crash for api level < 19
    android:title="@string/title_home" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard_black_24dp" //this works normally
    android:title="@string/title_dashboard" />
```

jellybean crashes and give this error

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
```

i couldnt find any information at [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView)

so how can i edit a menu item with an image

Comment: in which folder is the phone.png present? Also is there a `cause` message within the stack trace

Comment: @peshkira normally i just paste it to drawable folder but just noticed i have to paste it to all folders. It is working on jellybean also.

Thanks 
write this as an answer and i will make this answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably put the png file in the wrong folder. Please recheck if it is in all the correct folders and try again.